# In Ramda.js, why must use identity to get `R.countBy()` to work?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

My apologies if this is a duplicate. I didn't find an answer elsewhere.

Ramda.js provides the `countBy()` function. From the documentation we can see:

```js
const R = require("ramda")

const letters = ['a', 'b', 'A', 'a', 'B', 'c'];
R.countBy(R.toLower)(letters);   //=> {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```

But what if we already have our `letters` in lowercase? That is, we don't need any extra step, but just to count. For example, let's say I want to simply count `letters2` array:

```js
const letters2 = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
R.countBy(letters2) // doesn't work
```

Instead, we must add some identity expression such as:

```js
R.countBy(x => x)(letters2)
// gives {"a": 4, "b": 2, "c": 4}
```

or

```js
R.countBy(R.identity)(letters2)
```

This isn't always the case with other Ramda functions (e.g., `R.isNil()`). I'm trying to understand where this extra step of identity comes from. To me it seems unnecessary, but I'm probably missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Ramda functions with the “By” suffix do the action with a provided predicate. In this case, it counts by the predicate given.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "predicate", `countBy` accepts a normalise function instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that ramda simply does not make any assumption on how you want to count your list...

```js
const  list = ['A', 'b', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'G', 'F'];

// simply count
console.log(
  R.countBy(R.identity, list),
)


// or count case insensitively
console.log(
  R.countBy(R.toLower, list),
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-ZZcBsXW4OcbCTfDlXbzGCamH1cANkg6EfZAN2ukOl7s5q8skbB+WndmAqFT8fuMzeuHkceqd5UbIDn7fcqJFgg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

---

Also, do not forget that you can build up your functions by leveraging partial application.

Note the wording, `countBy` as if Ramda wants to be told how to count. but nothing prevents you from building your own count.

```
const count = R.countBy(R.identity);

console.log(count(list))
```

Comment: Exactly.  See any of these: `filter (endsWith ('By'), keys (R)) //=> ["collectBy", "countBy", "eqBy", "groupBy", "indexBy", "maxBy", "minBy", "pickBy", "reduceBy", "sortBy", "uniqBy"]` (except `pickBy`, which is an unfortunate exception.)